# Formula in Excel to lookup for approximate match based on average, using Index/Match

Tags: excel, indexing, match, approximate

How can I use excel formulae such as VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH to lookup a value from a range, based on the mean of the upper and lower values when exact match is not available. e.g.

**Range:**

| A. | B. |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 123 |
| 125 | 234 |
| 175 | 345 |
| 276 | 547 |

| C Input | D Lookup value |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 345 |
| 250 | 547 |

Since 200 does not have an exact match in column A, I need the value corresponding to 175 because 200 is less than the mean (175+276)/2 (=225); similarly 250 has a lookup value of 547 because 250>225.

I have tried:

```
= INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH(TRUE,A1:A4>C1,0)) --> always gives the upper bound
```

```
= VLOOKUP(C2,$A$1:$B$4,2,TRUE) --> always gives lower bound
```

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$4)/(ABS($A$1:$A$4-C1)=MIN(ABS($A$1:$A$4-C1))),1))
```

[image]